# implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString*'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

```
//This is to give a general idea of what is being called
int realQuestionIndex;
realQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex;
currentQuestionIndex = 0;

//The below code is where I'm receiving the error
questionIndexLabel.text = NSStringf(@"%d", realQuestionIndex+1);
//The updated code with NSString stringWithFormat producing error
questionIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%d",realQuestionIndex+1)];
```

I'm fixing bugs from someone else's project and I've never used NSStringf before.  I was advised to use NSString stringWithFormat..but I still receive the same error.  Any ideas?  sorry for the newbie questions!

Comment: What is `NSStringf` supposed to be? Use `NSString stringWithFormat:`. Update your question with how you try to use `stringWithFormat:`

Comment: What specific code did you use while trying to use stringWithFormat? Edit: Just realized rmaddy asked the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure either...but that's what the previous coder had.  when I change it to NSString stringWithFormat: I get the same error but here is the updated code
    questionIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%d", realQuestionIndex+1)];

Comment: @user3320964 Not sure if it'll make a difference but remove the parentheses in your stringWithFormat expression, i.e. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", realQuestionIndex+1];`

Comment: annnnnd i feel like an idiot..can't say thank you enough everyone..my progress is painfully slow but appreciate you all taking the time

Comment: @LyndseyScott Removing the parentheses will make a HUGE difference. They are the problem.

Comment: @LyndseyScott
Can i ask a follow up dumb question...when I type in the method NSString stringWithFormat it gives me an auto complete of including brackets for example.  Is that just a suggestion or it will always do that and I should know better?
    stringWithFormat:<#(NSString *), ...#>

Comment: @user3320964 You can find info about using stringWithFormat in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943

Comment: @user3320964, those "<#" things are markup that tell the source editor that those are parameters that are supposed to be replace with real text. If you press enter to copy the auto-completed text into your code, note that the parameters are highlighted. If you then press tab, the editor selects the next parameter that you need to enter so you can replace that bit of boilerplate with a real parameter. Then press tab again and it moves to the next parameter. Kinda handy, unless you try to copy the auto-complete code somewhere outside of the Xcode editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that NSStringf() is a preprocessor macro that is #defined in some header file that these files include. It probably just creates a call to stringWithFormat.

That's pointless and ugly. Just use the normal stringWithFormat syntax, as others have already explained in the comments:

```
questionIndexLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",realQuestionIndex+1];
```

(with no parenthesis)

@LyndseyScott, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it and you get credit for it.

Comment: You should explain why the parentheses cause the error. It's a detail I'd assume many people don't understand.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the parentheses do to the expression syntax other than bollocks it up.

Comment: The parentheses cause the `@"%d",realQuestionIndex+1` part to be treated as a single parameter instead of two separate, comma separated parameters to the method. In C (and hence, Objective-C), a group of expressions separated by commas is ultimately given the value of the result of the last expression in the list. This means that `(@"%d",realQuestionIndex+1)` has the value of `realQuestionIndex+1` which is an `int`. So the result is equivalent to `[NSString stringWithFormat:realQuestionIndex+1];` which of course isn't correct.